# как у React устроен hook useState?

Tags: reactjs, hook, state, react-hook

Я понимаю что в React hook useState возвращает массив где есть значение и функция для его установки - `[state, setState]`. Но как он устанавливает значение при вызове setState? Если можно написать класс где есть функция setState, которая работает как и в React. Конечно не надо писать большой функционал, render и т.д. минимальный набор, что бы можно было сделать `const [str, setStr] = useState('a');`, и потом при вызове `setStr` значение переменной str менялось, вот и все. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: setState работает. Значение устанавливает асинхронно. Как конкретно -- детали реализации, которые могут меняться. Тут надо писать движок целый, как отдельно -- не представляю пока.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

предполагаю, что так))

```
function useState(defaultValue) {
    const currentState = defaultValue;

    function stateSetter(value) {
        currentState = value;
        // дальше триггер для обновления компонента
    }

    return [currentState, stateSetter];
}
```

Comment: ну, так, если совсем упрощать. Там же очередь из set-ов, группировка для оптимизации...

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, КАНЕШН, но главный вопрос автора, если я правильно прочитал, прозвучал как *Но как он устанавливает значение при вызове setState?*.

Comment: Спасибо, примерно так и думал :)

Comment: @PROCODE, кстати, вот в [этой статье](https://itnext.io/under-the-hood-of-react-hooks-805dc68581c3) классно описано что и как. и не благодарите)